# Instantiate a generic service using Ninject

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I have an generic interface for a service like this:

```
public interface IProductService<T> where T:Product
{
    Task<T> LoadProduct(int productID, int cateogryId, string key);
}
```

The default implementation is

```
public class ProductService<T>: IProductService<T> where T:Product
{ ... }
```

I want to use Ninject (and possibly Ninject.Extensions.Factory) to instantiate the service at runtime like this:

```
ProductService<Toy> productService = productServiceFactory.CreateProductService("Toy");
```

Where nameOfProductClass will be the actual product class derived from Product base class (in other words, T). I can't figure out how to do this. I can easily create a service like this:

```
var productService = productServiceFactory.CreateProductService<Toy>();
```

where Toy is derived from Product. If you notice, this requires me to actually put the product type in code before calling it. I don't want that, I want to pass the type name as argument.

Comment: What's the purpose of this? What will be the type of object you receive from productServiceFactory.CreateProductService("nameOfProductClass")?

Comment: @raderick I edited to make it somewhat clearer. The purpose is that controller will get a specific type of service and that service will return a specific type of product (Toy in this example). This way the controller won't have to cast from product to Toy, and consequently when new product types are added, controller won't have to change.

Comment: The problem here in your case is that your **IProductService** has generic argument of type **T:Product**, which means that to make operations with it you will have to return **IProductService<T>** from **productServiceFactory.CreateProductService("Toy")** method, and you cannot determine type of **T** in this case, so technically all you can receive from that method is **IProductService<Product>**. You should think of another way to make your controller methods generic.

Comment: You are already storing the result inside a `ProductService<Toy>` variable. This means that this code knows that it requires a service of for type `Toy`. why then you don't want the `CreateProductService` method call to specify `Toy` as a type?

Comment: The controller doesn't know product type at compile time. Product Type is retrieved from the database and the controller only expects a ProductService<T>, so it can call productService.LoadProduct(...)

Comment: Can you show an example of that? In your question, your are using a `ProductService<Toy>`. Please provide a complete example.

Comment: You can make a **ProductController<T> where T:Product** and then do all generic code there, and then create specific controllers - **ToyController : ProductController<Toy>** that will differ with generic parameter type, some specific code and **RoutePrefix**, which will allow you to have generic code working in a pretty simple way + make it simply extendable - it will also allow you to add concrete code for specific entities in your controller action if designed properly